# How to not use Firebase Topics Messaging and Device Group Messaging?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Wanted to ask in my special case about sending FCM. I read about the Firebase [Topic messaging and  Device group messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple) but dont think it will work in my scenario.

I have a Firebase connected app that need help!

I want to create a place where the app user can send a chat message and there is nobody listening, or there could be a million+ people listening.

There are millions or even billions of chat rooms and there is no way to tell how many are listening on any chat, there could be miljons billions listening, there could be this many notifications to inform users that a new message is posted

When a user sends the chat a message, the notification must be sent to everyone who is listening.

how could I do this?

Comment: It sounds like you need Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: yea maybe, Do you mean like, let each user who is register for a particulate chat to listen on a Firebase Realtime Database key? But what if user is not currently using the app, that user will not get the message right?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Firebase database to create a chat app as you seek. There are tons of tutorials for that specific application actually.

Typically, the structure would look something like this:

```
{
  "chats": {
    "one": {
      "title": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "lastMessage": "ghopper: Relay malfunction found. Cause: moth.",
      "timestamp": 1459361875666
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },

  "members": {
    "one": {
      "ghopper": true,
      "alovelace": true,
      "eclarke": true
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  },

  "messages": {
    "one": {
      "m1": {
        "name": "eclarke",
        "message": "The relay seems to be malfunctioning.",
        "timestamp": 1459361875337
      },
      "m2": { ... },
      "m3": { ... }
    },
    "two": { ... },
    "three": { ... }
  }
}
```

([source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data))

So whenever a user sends a message through your app, you'd just create a new node under `messages` and update the appropriate entry under `chats`. I'd post more about the client-side process, but I'm not sure which platform you're using

*EDIT*

To clarify a bit further, you should listen to the `chats` node on your platform for any changes, once the `timestamp` of the last message changes from what you have stored on device, you check `messages`. That, or you can simply listen for `childAdded` in `messages`.

Regarding your comment, you don't really need FCM in this case unless you want to push notifications, in which case you'll need your own server for that to listen for the changes as well and dispatch the notifications appropriately.

Comment: What about security when "So whenever a user sends a message through your app" - The FCM server key is needed right?

Comment: Thanks for clarify but what if user is not currently using the app, that user will not get the message right? yea I know about "need your own server". I just wanted to ask this Q to get some vibes

Comment: Sure thing! :-) I'd also like to point out that FCM's "messaging" is more of a notifications service than instant messaging. And yes, the users will need to be using the app to receive the messages. In order to "push" those messages to the app, you'll need to set up your own server that will do the same thing (listen to Firebase database nodes) and push those messages using FCM or any other mean.